# SwiftUI PresentationButton Stops Functioning After Single Use on watchOS

Tags: swiftui

The PresentationButton presents the view properly, but upon hitting "Cancel" to return to parent view, the button refuses to present the child view again.

Here is my PresentationButton code:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            PresentationButton(Text("Click to show"), destination: SomeOtherView())
                .transition(.slide)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the current version. I don't see any relevant bugs registered at https://bugs.swift.org, but someone mentioned here (https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/by2a1r/swiftui_modal_presentation_bug/?ref=readnext) that this was reported to Apple engineers and they acknowledged it.

Comment: Its just not watchOS. On iOS also, its buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has existed in various forms until Xcode 11 beta 4, but note that the API has changed.

`PresentationButton` became `PresentationLink` and then was deprecated in Xcode 11 beta 4 in favor of `.sheet`.

See here for an example of how to use the new functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57087399/3179416