# Cannot assign value of type 'MenuView' to type 'some View'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I noticed that you can only have a single `.popover` modifier in SwiftUI. I have to present two possible simple popovers, one of them a `MenuView`, the other a `CreateChannelView`.

For that I have:

```
@State private var popover: some View
@State private var showPopover = false
```

and then the modifier:

```
.popover(isPresented: self.$showPopover) {
    self.popover
}
```

The problem is that I don't see how can I assign instances of `MenuView` or `CreateChannelView` to `popover` as I get the error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'MenuView' to type 'some View'

This is a little bit different than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56938805/1049134) which passes generic views in the `init` method.

Comment: some View - means one concrete type that conforms to View co it cannot once be MenuView and other time be CreateChannelView.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was to use `AnyView`:

```
@State private var popover: AnyView
```

Then it can be assigned as:

```
self.popover = AnyView(CreateChannelView(showing: self.$showPopover))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the two views as two different variables and then toggle selection between them with a boolean that determines which is presented. I made an example program with the information you gave me:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    let buttonSize: CGFloat = 30
    @State var isPresented = false
    @State var usePopover1 = true
    var popover1: some View {
        Text("Popover 1")
    }
    var popover2: some View {
        Image(systemName: "star")
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.isPresented = true
            }) {
                Text("Present popover")
            }
            Button(action: {
                self.usePopover1.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Switch from \(self.usePopover1 ? "popover1" : "popover2") to \(self.usePopover1 ? "popover2" : "popover1")")
            }
        }.popover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            if self.usePopover1 {
                AnyView(self.popover1)
            } else {
                AnyView(self.popover2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just made the two popovers on the spot for demonstration purposes, but you can declare yours as being the two different types you mentioned in your question (`let popover1: MenuView = MenuView(...)` and `let popover2: CreateChannelView = CreateChannelView(...)`).

Comment: Can you share some reading about this? Because it looks so strange that you define `some views` and then you have to wrap them in any views…

Comment: `some View` specifies that the popovers will be, as the syntax suggests, some type of view, however they retain their original typing. `popover1` is still a `Text` and `popover2` is still an `Image`. The `.popover` requires that the closure returns a uniform type, and since `popover1` and `popover2` are different types, we wrap both in `AnyView`.