# Cannot assign value of type 'some View' to type 'some View'

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I just started learning SwiftUI, and tried to call a method which returns a View, to a variable of type View, but get this surprising error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'some View' 
(result of 'Self.frame(width:height:alignment:)') 
to type 'some View' 
(result of 'Self.fill(_:style:)')
```

I wanted to try framing a view, just to see what would happen, to understand how SwiftUI arrives at dimensions for things.

```
    let p = Path({ (path:inout Path) -> () in
        path.addRect(CGRect(
            x:0,
            y:0,
            width:geometry.size.width,
            height:geometry.size.height
        ))
    })
    var result = p.fill(Color.red)
    result = result.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
```

What I think is happening here is that first I'm creating a `struct Path`, and calling its fill method turns it into a View. When I set `var result` to this return value, it should be inferred to have type `View`, which XCode says it does.

[image]

Since the View protocol has a `frame(width:height:alignment:) -> some View` method, I call that to get a new View. Now since `result` is inferred to be a View, and I'm assigning to it the result of `frame`, also a View, shouldn't that be legal?

(On [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493543/cannot-assign-value-of-type-menuview-to-type-some-view) someone commented *"some View - means one concrete type that conforms to View co it cannot once be MenuView and other time be CreateChannelView."*. Could that be the case here? If so, I'd also like know how to see what concrete type a method returns.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

> ```
> var result = p.fill(Color.red)
> result = result.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
> ```

use directly combined view as

```
return p.fill(Color.red).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
```

The `some View` means *some opaque concrete view type* but to use assignment the type *must* be the same however modifiers `.fill` and `.frame` produce different concrete types, that's why your assignment generated error.

Comment: Is there a way to declare a variable that can hold anything that conforms to the View protocol? Looks like there used to be `var result:protocol <View>` but it no longer works.