# Add view as a parameter to a custom ViewModifier

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is more of a syntactic question. I am trying to pass a view into a ViewModifier initialiser without using AnyView.

Currently I have something running using AnyView, but I would like to use the generic view syntax as you would then passing a "some view" to a view outlined in this answer here:

[How to pass one SwiftUI View as a variable to another View struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938805/how-to-pass-one-swiftui-view-as-a-variable-to-another-view-struct)

I cant seem to get it working with a ViewModifier.

The intention (as shown in the sample) is for the modifier to pass in a computed value into the innerView. I would also be happy with using @ViewBuilder somehow to specify the innerView property as this would probably have the same effect.

Here is the sample modifier:

```
struct SampleModifier: ViewModifier {

    let param1: CGFloat
    let innerView:  (CGFloat, CGFloat) -> AnyView
    
    // Assume these are calculated states
    let calculatedParam1: CGFloat = 100
    let calculatedParam2: CGFloat = 100
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()

                innerView(self.calculatedParam1, self.calculatedParam2)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                    .frame(width: param1)
            }
            
            content.frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        }
        
    }
}
```

And its use:

```
struct SampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .modifier(SampleModifier(param1: 150, innerView: { param1, param2 in
                return AnyView(
                    Text("Inner View: \(param1) - \(param2)")
                )
            }))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use generics, i.e., make `innerView` returning *some* view:

```
struct SampleModifier<V>: ViewModifier where V: View {
    let param1: CGFloat
    let innerView: (CGFloat, CGFloat) -> V

    ...
}
```

Then you don't need `AnyView` anymore:

```
struct SampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .modifier(SampleModifier(param1: 150, innerView: { param1, param2 in
                Text("Inner View: \(param1) - \(param2)")
            }))
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can create a `View` extension:

```
extension View {
    func sampleModifier<V>(
        param1: CGFloat,
        innerView: @escaping (CGFloat, CGFloat) -> V
    ) -> some View where V: View {
        modifier(SampleModifier(param1: param1, innerView: innerView))
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
struct SampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .sampleModifier(param1: 150, innerView: { param1, param2 in
                Text("Inner View: \(param1) - \(param2)")
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is EXACTLY what I was looking for. One more question, if I were to do a view extension helper function, what would it look like? I am really battling with syntax when combining generics and protocols.

Comment: @Slappy I updated my answer with a View extension.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the correct answer of [@pawello2222](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8697793/pawello2222), to fulfil the original request:

> I would also be happy with using @ViewBuilder somehow to specify the innerView property as this would probably have the same effect.

just add `@ViewBuilder` as parameter attribute to the `innerView` parameter:

```
extension View {
    func sampleModifier<V>(
        param1: CGFloat,
        @ViewBuilder innerView: @escaping (CGFloat, CGFloat) -> V
    ) -> some View where V: View {
        modifier(SampleModifier(param1: param1, innerView: innerView))
    }
}
```