# SwiftUI: create iOS16-compatible contextMenu

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to use the new contextMenu modifier with 'preview', while also supporting iOS15. I'm trying to create a `ViewModifier` for this so that I can do the availability check there, but I'm having a tough time getting a grip of the syntax for 'generic' parameters here.

This is what I was trying:

```
struct CompatiblityContextMenuModifier: ViewModifier {

@ViewBuilder let actionsList: Group<Any>
@ViewBuilder let actionsPreview: any View

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *){
        content
            .contextMenu(menuItems: actionsList, preview: actionsPreview)
    } else {
        content
            .contextMenu(menuItems: actionsList)
    }
}
```

}

But the compiler complains:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'any View' to expected argument type '() -> P'
Cannot convert value of type 'Group<Any>' to expected argument type '() -> M'
Generic parameter 'M' could not be inferred
Generic parameter 'P' could not be inferred
```

I know I need to specify a different 'type' for the actionsList and actionPreview, but what exactly would that be?

This is what the function call for contextMenu looks like:

```
func contextMenu<M, P>(
    @ViewBuilder menuItems: () -> M,
    @ViewBuilder preview: () -> P
) -> some View where M : View, P : View
```

What exactly is "() -> M" and "() -> P"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is what I have, so far.  In order to incorporate `View` as an argument into `ViewModifier`, you need a specific technique.  [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65401146/add-view-as-a-parameter-to-a-custom-viewmodifier) has been helpful.  In this case, you have to incorporate two sets of `View`, which I have somehow managed by trial and error.

```
struct CompatiblityContextMenuModifier<V, I>: ViewModifier where V: View, I: View {
    let actionsList: () -> V
    let image: () -> I
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *){
            content
                .contextMenu(menuItems: actionsList, preview: image)
        } else {
            content
                .contextMenu(menuItems: actionsList)
        }
    }
}
```

The following is how I test it for iOS 16.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .modifier(CompatiblityContextMenuModifier(actionsList: {
                Group {
                    Button {
                    } label: {
                        Label("Add to Favorites", systemImage: "heart")
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                    } label: {
                        Label("Show in Maps", systemImage: "mappin")
                    }
                }
            }, image: {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 256)
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
            }))
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

View and Group which are not directly compatible with the types expected by contextMenu. Also, SwiftUI’s contextMenu modifier doesn’t accept a Group as its menuItems parameter. Instead, it expects a closure that returns some View.

To fix the issue and create a generic ViewModifier, you can use the @ViewBuilder attribute for the actions closure and use a generic type placeholder for the preview which conforms to View. Here’s how you can do it:

```
struct CompatibilityContextMenuModifier<Preview: View>: ViewModifier {
let menuItems: () -> AnyView
var preview: (() -> Preview)?

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        content
            .contextMenu {
                menuItems()
            } preview: {
                preview?()
            }
    } else {
        content
            .contextMenu {
                menuItems()
            }
    }
}
```

}

You can provide a closure for the menu items and optionally for the preview when you’re on iOS 16 or later:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
        .modifier(CompatibilityContextMenuModifier(menuItems: {
            AnyView(Group {
                Button("Action 1", action: { /* ... */ })
                Button("Action 2", action: { /* ... */ })
            })
        }, preview: {
            Text("Preview")
        }))
}
```

}

This way, you provide a closure that returns the menu items and, conditionally, a closure that returns the preview content. This should compile correctly and give you the desired behavior on both iOS 15 and iOS 16.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to compile. I get an error on the first line "let menuItems: () -> View" ... error says "Use of protocol 'View' as a type must be written 'any View'"

Comment: I have updated the code check now.