# Pass a SwiftUI view that has its own arguments as a variable to another view struct

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I'll try to outline my case here, I have a `NavigationLink` I'm wanting to turn into it's own structure so I can re-use it. The `Label` inside the `NavigationLink` is the same for all the cases I'm using, just different text and images. I'm trying to make that new struct that contains the `NavigationLink` have an argument I use for the destination View of the `NavigationLink`.

I found this link that got me most of the way, but I just don't seem to be able to get it the last mile.

[How to pass one SwiftUI View as a variable to another View struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938805/how-to-pass-one-swiftui-view-as-a-variable-to-another-view-struct)

Here is the re-usable `NavigationLink` struct I made:

```
struct MainMenuButtonView<Content: View>: View {
    
    var imageName: String
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: content) {
                Image(imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                Text(title)
                    .font(.title)
                Text(description)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray2))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .frame(width: 175)
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

I currently don't get any errors on that part, but that doesn't mean there isn't something wrong with it.

And here is where I'm using it at, currently, I just shown one, but I'll have more once I get it working.

```
struct MainMenuView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MainMenuButtonView(imageName: "List Icon",
                               title: "Lists",
                               description: "Auto generated shopping lists by store",
                               content: TestMainView(testText: "Lists"))
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Main Menu"))
        }
    }
}
```

When I leave it as above, it tells me that there is an extra argument and that 'Contect' can't be inferred. Xcode does offer a fix, and it ends up looking like this after I do the fix

```
MainMenuButtonView<Content: View>(imageName: "List Icon",
```

But then I get an error that it cannot find 'Content' in scope. I know the main difference between my question and the example I linked above is my View I'm passing in also has arguments. I'm not sure if I'm also supposed to put all the arguments in the callout within the <>.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to correct the `init` in the `MainMenuButtonView`:

```
struct MainMenuButtonView<Content: View>: View {
    var imageName: String
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var content: () -> Content // change to closure

    // add all parameters in the init
    init(imageName: String, title: String, description: String, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.imageName = imageName // assign all the parameters, not only `content`
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: content()) { // use `content()`
                Image(imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                Text(title)
                    .font(.title)
                Text(description)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray2))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .frame(width: 175)
            }
            .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you need to pass a *closure* to the `content` parameter (as you indicated in the `init`):

```
struct MainMenuView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MainMenuButtonView(
                imageName: "List Icon",
                title: "Lists",
                description: "Auto generated shopping lists by store",
                content: { TestMainView(testText: "Lists") } // pass as a closure
            )
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Main Menu"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thank you! I just realized I still had the NavigationLink in the MainMenuView as well, so anyone reading, you don't need it in both places.

Comment: @JasonBrady Right, I didn't notice - I removed the extra `NavigationLink` from my answer.

Comment: I did the same on mine too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the builder empty or nil, you can do it like this:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
     content: (() -> any View)?
     init() {
          self.content = nil
     }
     init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> any View) {
          self.content = content
     }
     public var body: some View {
          ...
          if let content {
             AnyView(content())
          }
          ...
     }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
var body: some View {
    ExampleView()
    ExampleView {
        Color.blue
    }
}
```