# Routing with a generic function

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I am trying to create a router. I intended to route directly to a view in the body such as..

```
struct MyView: View {
  let page: Page
   var body: some View {
     router(page: page)
    }
 }
```

In the body I tried to declare a function...

```
func router(page: Page) -> View
```

which gave me the error:

```
Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

so I then made it

```
func router<T: View>(page: Page) -> T
```

then in the body I used a switch statement:

```
 func router<T: View>(page: Page) -> T {

switch page {
  case .page1: 
     return Page1()
        ....

 }
}
```

then Xcode recommended that I cast all returned views `as! T`

which ultimately led me to the generic warning against generics as been below:

[image: Text]

I search SO for this problem and there are many variants but none led to me understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass one SwiftUI View as a variable to another View struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938805/how-to-pass-one-swiftui-view-as-a-variable-to-another-view-struct)

Comment: @loremipsum It looks like it might but its a deep dive and I am literally burnt out for the night, thanks for the reference, will read when I can come to my senses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you're overcomplicating things a bit.  Your router function can just return `some View` like your other `body` functions can:

```
enum AirFormulas {
    case formula1
    case formula2
}

struct RouterView : View {
    let formula : AirFormulas
    var body: some View {
        router(formula: formula)
    }
}

@ViewBuilder func router(formula: AirFormulas) -> some View {
    switch formula {
    case .formula1:
        Text("Hi")
    case .formula2:
        Image(systemName: "plus")
    }
}
```

Note a couple of things:

1. I used `@ViewBuilder` so that I could return a variety of `View` types from the function. It also means I'm not going to explicitly call `return`. More reading: https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/12/18/the-power-of-viewbuilder-in-swiftui/
2. Another (uglier) way to do this is to wrap all of the returned values with `AnyView` and return `AnyView` instead of `some View`

Finally, why you were getting the error:
In the case of your original code, `T` couldn't be inferred because there was nothing to infer it from.  You pass an `AirFormulas`, which has no information about `T`.  And the return value can be a variety of `View` types, but that's what we use `some View` to achieve.

Comment: Thanks, that led to quick understanding and gave me food for thought for the future on understanding more about ViewBuilders