# How do I make a preferenceKey accept a View in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to build a custom NavigationView, and I'm struggling with how to implement a custom ".navigationBarItems(leading: /* insert views */, trailing: /* insert Views */)". I assume I have to use a preferenceKey, but I don't know how to make it accept views.

My top menu looks something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TopMenu<Left: View, Right: View>: View {
    
    let leading: Left
    let trailing: Right
    
    init(@ViewBuilder left: @escaping () -> Left, @ViewBuilder right: @escaping () -> Right) {
        self.leading = left()
        self.trailing = right()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            HStack {
                
                leading
                
                Spacer()
                
                trailing
                
            }.frame(height: 30, alignment: .center)
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
        
    }
}

struct TopMenu_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TopMenu(left: { }, right: { })
    }
}
```

And this is my attempt at creating a preferenceKey to update it with, where I've obviously missed something very basic:

```
struct TopMenuItemsLeading: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue:View
    
    
    static func reduce(value: inout View, nextValue: () -> View) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct TopMenuItemsTrailing: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue:View
    
    
    static func reduce(value: inout View, nextValue: () -> View) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

extension View {
    func topMenuItems(leading: View, trailing: View) -> some View {
        self.preference(key: TopMenuItemsLeading.self, value: leading)
        self.preference(key: TopMenuItemsTrailing.self, value: trailing)
    }
}
```

Comment: `navigationBarItems()` is being [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbaritems(leading:trailing:)) switch to a `.toolbar` pattern. [Passing a `View`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938805/how-to-pass-one-swiftui-view-as-a-variable-to-another-view-struct) has been asked several times in SO

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass one SwiftUI View as a variable to another View struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938805/how-to-pass-one-swiftui-view-as-a-variable-to-another-view-struct)

Comment: Thank you, but not exactly. I'm passing a view as a variable myself in the sample code above. That's not what I'm struggling with. It is using a View as a preferenceKey that has me stumped. I've tried passing a view to my preferenceKey as I'd normally do it in a view, but it's not working as I expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so there was some great partial answers in here, but none that actually achieved what I asked, which was to pass a view up the view-hierarchy using a preferenceKey. Essentially what the .navigationBarItems method is doing, but with my own custom view.

I found a solution however, so here goes (and apologies if I missed any obvious short-cuts. This IS my first time using preferenceKeys for anything):

``````
import SwiftUI

struct TopMenu: View {
    
    @State private var show:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TopMenuView {
                
                Button("Change", action: { show.toggle() })
                
                Text("Hello world!")
                    .topMenuItems(leading: Image(systemName: show ? "xmark.circle" : "pencil"))
                    .topMenuItems(trailing: Image(systemName: show ? "pencil" : "xmark.circle"))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TopMenu_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TopMenu()
    }
}

/*

To emulate .navigationBarItems(leading: View, trailing: View), I need four things:
 
    1) EquatableViewContainer - Because preferenceKeys need to be equatable to be able to update when a change occurred
    2) PreferenceKeys - That use the EquatableViewContainer for both leading and trailing views
    3) ViewExtenstions - That allow us to set the preferenceKeys individually or one at a time
    4) TopMenu view - That we can set somewhere higher in the view hierarchy.
 
 */

// First, create an EquatableViewContainer we can use as preferenceKey data
struct EquatableViewContainer: Equatable {
    
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let view:AnyView
    
    static func == (lhs: EquatableViewContainer, rhs: EquatableViewContainer) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

// Second, define preferenceKeys that uses the Equatable view container
struct TopMenuItemsLeading: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: EquatableViewContainer = EquatableViewContainer(view: AnyView(EmptyView()) )
    
    static func reduce(value: inout EquatableViewContainer, nextValue: () -> EquatableViewContainer) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct TopMenuItemsTrailing: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: EquatableViewContainer = EquatableViewContainer(view: AnyView(EmptyView()) )
    
    static func reduce(value: inout EquatableViewContainer, nextValue: () -> EquatableViewContainer) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

// Third, create view-extensions for each of the ways to modify the TopMenu
extension View {
    
    // Change only leading view
    func topMenuItems<LView: View>(leading: LView) -> some View {
        self
            .preference(key: TopMenuItemsLeading.self, value: EquatableViewContainer(view: AnyView(leading)))
    }
    
    // Change only trailing view
    func topMenuItems<RView: View>(trailing: RView) -> some View {
        self
            .preference(key: TopMenuItemsTrailing.self, value: EquatableViewContainer(view: AnyView(trailing)))
    }
    
    // Change both leading and trailing views
    func topMenuItems<LView: View, TView: View>(leading: LView, trailing: TView) -> some View {
        self
            .preference(key: TopMenuItemsLeading.self, value: EquatableViewContainer(view: AnyView(leading)))
    }
}


// Fourth, create the view for the TopMenu
struct TopMenuView<Content: View>: View {
    
    // Content to put into the menu
    let content: Content
    
    @State private var leading:EquatableViewContainer = EquatableViewContainer(view: AnyView(EmptyView()))
    @State private var trailing:EquatableViewContainer = EquatableViewContainer(view: AnyView(EmptyView()))
    
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            
            ZStack {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    leading.view
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    trailing.view
                    
                }
                
                Text("TopMenu").fontWeight(.black)
            }
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 2, bottom: 5, trailing: 2))
            .background(Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top))
            
            content
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(TopMenuItemsLeading.self, perform: { value in
            leading = value
        })
        .onPreferenceChange(TopMenuItemsTrailing.self, perform: { value in
            trailing = value
        })
        
    }
}
`````
``````

Comment: Pure genius! Thank you very much for taking the time to share your solution

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your solution! You are a savior!

Answer (score 0):

The possible approach is to use `AnyView`, like

```
struct TopMenuItemsLeading: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: AnyView = AnyView(EmptyView())
    
    
    static func reduce(value: inout AnyView, nextValue: () -> AnyView) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

struct TopMenuItemsTrailing: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: AnyView = AnyView(EmptyView())
    
    
    static func reduce(value: inout AnyView, nextValue: () -> AnyView) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

extension View {
    func topMenuItems<LView: View, TView: View>(leading: LView, trailing: TView) -> some View {
        self
          .preference(key: TopMenuItemsLeading.self, value: AnyView(leading))
          .preference(key: TopMenuItemsTrailing.self, value: AnyView(trailing))
    }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome thank you. The only downside to this approach is that the AnyView is a bit heavy to use. Isn't there any way to init the view somehow?

Comment: Have you measured its *weight* or just believed in someone's legend? ;)

Comment: Haha! I meant “performance heavy”. I’m no expert myself, but quoting Paul Hudson: “ Now, the logical conclusion here is to ask why we don’t use AnyView all the time if it lets us avoid the restrictions of some View. The answer is simple: performance. [...] As a result, it’s likely to have to do significantly more work to keep our user interface updated when regular changes happen, so it’s generally best to avoid AnyView unless you specifically need it.”

Comment: Key words *"unless you specifically need it"*

Comment: I tried using this, but since AnyView isn't equatable, I couldn't get onPreferenceChange to work. I therefore ended up using a custom object instead. I've posted my solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the initialiser of TopView to take `Views` like this:

```
struct TopMenu<Left: View, Right: View>: View {
    
    let leading: Left
    let trailing: Right
    
    init(left: Left,
         right: Right) {
        self.leading = left
        self.trailing = right
    }
    //etc.
```

And then declare the modifier similarly to how `navigationBarItems` modifiers are defined:

```
extension View {
    
    func topMenuItems<L, T>(leading: L, trailing: T) -> some View where L : View, T : View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            TopMenu(left: leading, right: trailing)
            self
        }
    }
    func topMenuItems<L>(leading: L) -> some View where L : View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            TopMenu(left: leading, right: EmptyView())
            self
        }
    }
    func topMenuItems<T>(trailing: T) -> some View where T : View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            TopMenu(left: EmptyView(), right: trailing)
            self
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but that would only work downwards in the view-hierarchy right? What I need is specifically to pass the view up to the topMenu from a subview.

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn’t work? It works for navigation bar items.

Comment: Hmm, I admit I’m no expert, but I thought preferenceKeys was the only alternative to bindings when passing information up the hierarchy. I’ll give it a test, and if this works I’ll mark it as answer, because it’s simpler than what I came up with,

Comment: Ok, I tested it, and unless I'm misunderstanding your proposal, then it doesn't update the same TopMenu, like my solution does. It just adds a new TopMenu around whatever view I add the modifier to. If you try the solution I added to the question, it might be easier to see what I was trying to achieve. Sorry if that wasn't clear enough.