# How to declare a function type which returns a View (Xcode 14 Beta1 - SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've been playing with the new release of SwiftUI and Xcode14, to explore all the new possibilities of programmatic navigation with `NavigationStack`. I've built a little example with a `NavigationLink` which takes a value as a parameter, and the `.navigationDestination` modifier , in which I use a switch statement to determine which View will be instantiated:

```
    enum Destination: String, CaseIterable, Hashable {
        case view1, view2 
    }

    struct Navigation: View {
    @State private var path: [Destination] = []
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            NavigationLink(value: Destination.view1, label: {
                Text("Go to View1")
            })
            .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self, destination: { path in
                switch path {
                    case .view1: View1()
                    case .view2: View2()
                }
            })
            .navigationTitle("Root View")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to refactor with the functional approach, trying to replace the switch by recalling an array of callbacks:

```
typealias Paths = [((Destination) -> Bool, () -> any View)]
private lazy var navigation: Paths = [
    ({ $0 == .view1 }, { View1() }),
    ({ $0 == .view2 }, { View2() })
 ]
```

replacing the switch statement with:

```
navigation.first { $0.0(path) }?.1()
```

I get this error here: `Type 'any View' cannot conform to 'View'`, and I don't seem to find a way to solve it.
Instead of `any View`, I would rather return `some View`, or even `View` itself, but neither of the two is possible, as both return errors. The only workaround I have found is by using `AnyView` instead, but in this way I permanently erase the the View type, which isn't great.

Thank you in advance for any guidance you can provide!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938805/how-to-pass-one-swiftui-view-as-a-variable-to-another-view-struct) help?

Comment: Exactly, good old generics should help. Did you try to define something like <V: View> somewhere like struct Navigation<V: View>: View and use it in your navigation declaration instead of any View?

Comment: Perhaps nitpicking, but the `switch` is also functional, as the closure is a pure function. And code-length wise, you don't gain much by converting to a dictionary-based solution, I'd even say that it makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 0):

Swift does not allow to put into array different types (and here types are different because depend on View1, View2, which are different, and View is generics protocol and cannot be used as array type)

A possible approach is to move view builder directly in type, so each case knows about own view, like

```
enum Destination: String, CaseIterable, Hashable {
    case view1, view2

    @ViewBuilder var view: some View {    // << here !!
        switch self {
        case .view1: View1()
        case .view2: View2()
        }
    }
}
```

and use even simpler

```
.navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { $0.view }
```

if arguments will be needed to inject into view constructor then a function can be used instead of computable property.

Tested with Xcode 14 / iOS 16