# Using Views as parameters for another View without AnyView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two views that I want to use as possible parameters in another view. I've been using AnyView, but would much rather use @ViewBuilder instead; I'm not 100% sure on how to implement this though.
See below:

View1

```
struct View1: View {
    let title: String
    let text: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(title)
            Text(text).bold()
        }
    }
}
```

View 2

```
struct View2: View {
    let title: String
    let text: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(title).bold()
            Text(text)
        }
    }
}
```

ParameterView - currently the `view` parameter being passed through is being wrapped in `AnyView()`.

```
struct ParameterView: View {
    let title: String
    let view: any View

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(title)
            AnyView(view)
        }
    }
}
```

In practice:

```
struct ParameterView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            ParameterView(
                title: "Noodles",
                view: View1(title: "£", text: "1.00")
            ) // Noodles £ 1.00

            ParameterView(
                title: "Mass",
                view: View2(title: "100", text: "g")
            ) // Mass 100 g
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938805/how-to-pass-one-swiftui-view-as-a-variable-to-another-view-struct

Comment: The question is closed, not deleted. There is no need to reopen it; it is a complete question answer cycle. Do not add an edit / update and do not ask for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're along the right lines - using @ViewBuilder is the way to go! We will combine this with the use of generics. I'll use your ParameterView as an example:

```
struct ParameterView<Content: View>: View {
    let title: String
    @ViewBuilder let view: Content

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(title)
            view
        }
    }
}
```

Here we're creating a view that uses a generic type `Content` that must conform to `View`. We use the `@ViewBuilder` property wrapper that basically says our property `view` is some function that will return a property of type `Content` and because `Content: View` we can use this property as we can with any `View`. Then all that's left to do is use that within the `body`.

Here's the usage:

```
struct UsageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ParameterView(title: "Noodles") {
            View1(title: "£", text: "1.00")
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using trailing closure syntax here because `@ViewBuilder` turns our property into a method.

Comment: This worked - thank you! I appreciate the detailed explanation. This was a lot clearer than the question linked.